# Why would someone put `where 1=1` in a query?

Tags: sql-server-2005

I came across a view in our database today where the first statement in the where clause was `where 1 = 1`. Shouldn't this return true for every record? Why would someone write this if it isn't filtering any records?

Comment: Answered here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/667/building-dynamic-oracle-where-clause

Comment: Because they want to hack sombodys website ;-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Some dynamic query builders include this condition so that any "real" conditions can be added with an `AND` without doing a check like `if (first condition) 'WHERE' else 'AND'`.

Comment: It sounds strange that a query builder can't determine wheter a condition is the first in a line, but I think also, you're right.

Comment: it's often the case when the "query builder" is someone writing code to concatenate onto the SQL statement by hand. sometimes introducing a more formal query building library eliminates it.

Comment: I've had to deal with "old" code like this, and it's very true.  When you're assembling the entire SQL statement into a single string, there will be bunches of if/then or case statements that may or may not trigger.  Because you never know if any of those code paths are taken, BUT you have an AND embedded in your WHERE clause (due to a clause that is consistently part of the string), you need to either (a) remove the offending AND or (b) simply pass it a logical truism.  Adding "1=1" is easier than redacting the string correctly.

Answer (score 5):

If you have many SQL statement building points in your program which generate *similar* queries, you can mark the examined one by this trick. If the sentence is about counting, you may use code below so you can grep out `42` from a SQL log.

```
select count(42) from table
```

Answer (score 4):

It provides a situation that is always true, so it doesn't affect the results, but you know there is one item in the WHERE clause already.

Answer (score 0):

It helps me with my test queries that I use often and have multiple condition that I add and remove

Note in oracle you can comment a line with --

```
SELECT
tablea.*,
--tableb.*,
tablec.*
 from dual
,tablea 
--,tableb 
,tablec
where 1=1
--and tablea.a = tableb.a
and tablea.a = tablec.a
and tablea = :value
```

I can easily add or remove tableb from the query